# Манипуляция содержимым страницы с помощью jQuery(get)

Tags: jquery, javascript

Доброго времени суток, уважаемые программисты. На этот раз задаю вопрос по поводу jQuery и использования содержимых других страниц. Объясню в чем именно вопрос. У меня есть сайт. На этом сайте есть страница. На этой странице, к примеру, ссылка. Пройдя по этой ссылки есть текстовое поле и ещё одна кнопка для отправки данных. Я хочу написать функцию, которая будет автоматически получать данные со страницы, переходить по ссылке, заполнять текстовое поле и отправлять данные. Как я понимаю, делать это нужно через get. Таким образом я получу DOM страницы, найду на ней нужную мне ссылку. Что будет происходить, если я, к примеру, нажму на эту кнопку? Как мне реализовать фоновую передачу данных таким образом?

Comment: домен один и тот-же участвует во всём сценарии ? jquery на браузере ? Какая кнопка имеется ввиду ? Как я понял вы можете для удобства организовать фрейм, скопировать туда форму и отправить все данные без самостоятельной сериализации формы.

Comment: Домен один и тот же. Делаю скрипт (greasemonkey), который использует данные этого сайта

Comment: в чем таки проблема ? предоставьте код

Comment: [не xhr](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/DBuTU/) [xhr](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/DBuTU/1)

Comment: Почитайте про протокол HTTP и Ajax

Comment: Я знаю, что такое Ajax. Но меня интересует реализация именно через get. Я знаю, что это возможно. Пока ещё до изучения Ajax я не дошел (но в скором времени планирую полностью посмотреть его). Хочется рассмотреть все возможные варианты реализации.

Comment: к сожалению, код предоставить не смогу. Выдергивание пары строк из целостного скрипта не будет целесообразно. Да и по сути кода-то нет. Тут скорее теоретический вопрос?

Comment: Ничего вы не знаете. $.get() это и есть ajax запрос. берите ваш ответ с пом-ю $.get(), превращайте его в dom и пользуйтесь для сабмита формы одним из примеров.

Comment: В таком случае прошу прощения. Просто, не увидев ни одного упоминания об ajax в документации (по get), решил, что это что-то иное